# Declare a variable in a subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I want a column with multiple values which are comma separated. How to declare a variable in a subquery which can contain multiple comma separated names. Declaring the variable name `@concatstring` throws error.

What is the alternative for this!

```
select distinct db_mainorders.orderid,vehicle,ordertype,
  (select clientname from db_client where db_client.clientid=db_mainorders.clientid)as calintname,
  (declare   @ConcatString  VARCHAR(max)
  select   @ConcatString = COALESCE(@ConcatString + ', ', '') + Name FROM db_depotstation where  
  db_depotstation.depotstationid in (select depotstationid from db_orderdetails where 
  db_orderdetails.orderid=db_mainorders.orderid and (pickordelivery like '%delivery%' OR pickordelivery like '%return%'))
  select   @ConcatString as consignee)
from db_mainorders 
left join db_orderdetails on db_orderdetails.orderid=db_mainorders.orderid
where cast(db_mainorders.assignedat as date) between '2015-12-01' and '2015-12-07'
```

Comment: I see what you are trying. This would be alot easier, if you provided test data, expected result and version of sqlserver.

Comment: [6 - Rajkiya Uchh Prathmik Vidyalaya - Jodla, 7 - Rajkiya Uchh Prathmik Vidyalaya - Badharana,.....,....] I want values like this in one column of a row.

Comment: Presently I am getting all values in different rows. They are not comma separated. They are coming like [  B BAGMANE TECH PARK,]
[B INDIRA NAGAR,]
[B JEEVAN BHIMA NAGAR,] each in a separate row